# Do multiple browsers run in same session

Tags: servlets

I wish to know if I open multiple browsers in eclipse at the same time running same web -app do they run on the same session or are the sessions different coz the session attribute values get shared.
Also what is more confusing is that if I try printing the sessionid cookie value across multiple browsers open at the same time all fetch the exactly same value.This should happen when the session is same for all.Isn't that so???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean multiple windows or tabs of the same browser, like three windows of Internet Explorer, each share the same session.

If you mean two different browser applications, like one window of Internet Explorer and one window of Firefox, each will have a different session.

By default, browser cookies are used to hold the session id that associates the client browser with the session. For example, any tab or window of Internet Explorer will have access to the same Internet Explorer cookies and so will all share the same session id cookie and so will all share the same session.

Answer (score 0):

To run on the same session that would mean that the same client socket would be used in all browser instances. So an *educated guess* would be no, the session would not be shared as each browser would use a different client connection.
But I don't know this for sure, so if no one here answers you knowing exactly what's going on under the hood, I would recommend to run your web app in a different machine and use a network monitoring tool, e.g. wireshark to see if each request goes over a different TCP connection.